# Failure to boot, with pciport error message

Tags: boot

I am running Ubuntu stable (22.04) on a Lenovo laptop. For the first time it failed to boot and, having left it overnight to try, left me with a single error message on bold:

[5170.503757] pciport 0000:00:1d.2: AER : Error of this Agent is reported first

I have no understanding of this and no previous problems over 2 years or so or running 22.04 on this laptop, other than occasional recent warning messages during operation about shortage of disk space (down to around 1GB) which I'm sorry I cannot retrieve as I cannot boot the laptop.

Comment: Do you get the same problem with 23.10? If you're out of disk space, that could be an issue preventing boot. It may be that this message is unrelated to your inability to boot

Comment: Boot Up a live Session and Check If your / filesystem is full.

Comment: Thank you yes the problem was a full file system, not specifically a boot problem